# memory, primitives and c

Tags: c

Say I'm declaring primitives or arrays of primitives (on the stack right).  How do I "free" or clean them up so they aren't taking/leaking memory?

For example:

```
int blah;
blah=7;
doSomethingWithBlah...
free(blah) //[?]
```

probably not a bit deal normally; but what if you had say a huge char array or whatever?

also any 'local' variables (that is, inside a function) will be by default 'auto' and are cleaned up automatically right [in Java terms, they are GCed when going out of scope).

Just curious, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't.

A stack is a data structure. It's LIFO (Last In, First Out) which means that the last thing that was put on the stack is the first one to be removed from the stack. Here's how you can think about this in programming:

main -> foo

The main function (entry point) calls some function foo. Certain variables are declared/defined in the main function. Others are declared in the foo function, which are at a different level of scope.

When you enter the program, all the vars declared in main are pushed onto a block of the stack. Same with foo when it is called, but the next block. Then when it reaches the end of the foo function, it pops that set of variables off the stack (or 'frees' them). When it reaches the end of the main function, it pops that set of variables off the stack.

So to answer your question, ALL local variables, including local arrays which are stored on the stack, are automatically deleted when they go out of scope. You never have to free those yourself.

You just worry about the stuff that you put on the heap, which is anytime you use "malloc" in C, or "new" in C++.

Comment: This is the most detail that I know, and I think what I've written is correct. Please correct me where I'm wrong or give me more information where I am lacking to improve my knowledge in this subject.

Comment: Thank.  Few questions though; what about Global vars?  (or one that will never go out of scope).  Is there any way to manually free them?  Theoretically say you allocate a huge char array to store an ascii file.  After you are done with using it (and assuming it will NOT go out of scope) is there any way to clean it up?  theoretically it should be on the heap I suppose.

Comment: As far as I know, global vars will simply go out of scope when the program exits. Although I believe they are not stored on the stack. I believe there is a certain portion of data/memory that is specifically for global vars. You might be able to learn more about that here: http://annwm.lbl.gov/~leggett/vars.html

Answer (score 1):

Local variables on the stack cease to exist when the stack frame is destroyed (i.e. when the function returns).  There's no way to remove them while their stack frame still exists.

If you need a large array, you should allocate it on the heap using `malloc()`, so that you can `free()` it when you're done with it.  (The *pointer* variable used to access the array remains on the stack, but that's small.)

Answer (score 1):

You don't "clean" or "free" data from the stack, there is no need since the memory is available for use again once the function returned. So `blah` should not be "cleaned" (but you can't pass a reference to it once the function return either...)

Comment: @user697111:  Then it is not allocated on the stack (they are stored in the program's *data* segment)

Answer (score 1):

To the best of my knowledge, local variables declared on the stack in C will be allocated as part of a function's activation record, and therefore reclaimed when the function returns.

I don't believe there's any way to "free" data declared on the stack.

Answer (score 1):

You can't. Stack variables are "freed" when they go out of scope (at the end of the containing block).

Large structures / arrays /etc you malloc on the heap.

Note that you say *"in Java terms, they are GCed when going out of scope"* ... this is incorrect and a bad way to think about things. All objects in java are created on the heap, and are made available to the garbage collector when there are no remaining references to them. This is very, very different than C where you can create things on the stack and (incorrectly) return pointers to them to a caller.